# Video is rendered at half the resolution

Tags: rendering

I want to create a 4k video of a 3d animation so I've set the resolution to 4096x2160, the file format to QuickTime and the video codec to H.264 but I always get a 2048x1080 video. Which are the right settings to get a full 4k video?

Answer (score 8):

Blenders default configuration sets the default resolution to 50%. Which means that it will render at half the size.

You can adjust these values in the properties panel under the 'scene tab'

For a full scale render set the resolution value to 100%

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is better to render your blender projects as images rather than videos because if you have render errors, it is easier to just re-render the failed image again instead of re-rendering the whole animation.

First of all, 4096x2160 is not UHD (4k) video resolution. The proper resolution for a 4k-UHD video would be 3840 × 2160.

I would try and render the animation as images with a resolution of 3840 × 2160. You could then use for example MakeAVI, to convert all your images to a video ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/makeavi/ ).

Comment: You can also use blender's video sequence editor instead of MakeAVI. Just open the Video Sequence editor, and at the bottom choose Add > Image. Select all your images, and import. Then go back to the rendering tab, and check Sequencer and uncheck Compositor. Then choose AVI or whatever video format you want under output, and render animation. It will stitch all the frames together and create the proper animation.

Comment: With regard to resolution - 4096x2160 is correct for DCI 4K, which _might_ be more appropriate for the OP's purposes.