# How to render in 4k?

Tags: animation

I've looked everywhere, but I have had no answer so far.I want to render my video so that when it's uploaded to a website (let's say youtube), there's an option to view it in beautiful, crisp, 4k quality. I made a video before of a model test, I added normals to the model, rendered it, uploaded it, and realized it was in 4k.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/video-is-rendered-at-half-the-resolution

Answer (score 5):

Just set the render resolution accordingly...using [DCI 4K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution):

[image]

Make sure to have the "percent" at 100%.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Ok, so i forgot to mention that my resolution sets are at a specific setting, so when I render it the black bars on the top and bottom looks like an actual movie. Is there another way?

Comment: @KingKong19100 there is also a simpler way. If you want the same resolution scale/aspect ratio, just change the percentage to 200%, which will double height and width and result in a 4k image.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to change the percentage to 200 so it could keep the same width and height ratios!